# PDFTeXify --- cannot remove a .synctex file

Tags: pdftex, miktex, winedt, forward-inverse-search

I use WinEdt 9.1, MikTeX 2.9, and Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

Sometimes when I `PDFTeXify` my document (`main.tex`), I get the following error

[image]

The `pdflatex.log` entries related to this specific compilation are

[image]

The `texify.log` entries related to this specific compilation are

[image]

This error started occurring this week, but it does not happen every time I compile. It is not clear to me when it does occur and when it does not; I have not found a pattern. It seems that the issue is that `main.synctex` is somehow locked, but I have no idea how to unlock the file during a compilation.

Comment: And now I get the same error as above again. Edit: Sometimes it actually does work and it nicely creates the .pdf. So it seems we can conclude that the there is not an error in any of the .tex files.

Comment: I might have resolved the problem. All of the files pertaining to this question are in my Google Drive folder. After compiling, Google Drive sees that a new version of a file has appeared and starts synchronizing. This seems to lock the file, making it impossible to remove it in the mean time. For now, disabling Google Drive solves the problem.

Comment: Well,then please self answer your question. That is welcome here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work (no errors for 1 full day):

All of the files pertaining to this question are in my Google Drive folder. While compiling, Google Drive sees that a new version of a file has appeared and starts synchronizing. This seems to lock the file, making it impossible to remove or change it in the mean time. `PDFTeXify` does multiple runs and encounters these locked files in subsequent runs, producing the error. For now, disabling Google Drive solves the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a way how to use latex in a google drive folder? I run into the same problem as you do, but as I use google drive quite extensively (I regularly work from three different computers), I would really appreciate a solution that does not require disabling Google Drive.

Comment: @Dominika Unfortunately, I have no other solution for you. I disable Google Drive when I work on .tex files and enable it when I am done.