# Need Winedt output files in a separate folder

Tags: winedt, pdfsync

I use WinEdt. How can I dump all output files (except .pdf) into a separate folder?

My main issue is that when files are stored locally in Google Drive, and sync is turned on, problems can occur when compiling a TeX file. ([see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310092/tex-based-solution-to-google-drive-sync-problems?noredirect=1&lq=1))

One solution is to dump all output files, except .pdf, into a local drive on my laptop that WinEdt could easily overwrite those files without google drive interruption. This is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/need-aux-file-in-separate-folder/7272#7272). However, I do not know how to do it in WInEdt.

Comment: create `TeXAuX` folder in map where you have file you compile.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:
Options --> Execution Modes --> Tex Options --> Uncheck the "Use %P if the folder doesn't exist."